# how to make a regular expression to accept

Tags: php, preg-replace, special-characters

how to make a regular expression to accept only alphanumeric characters, accents, Asian and Arab?

accept: `á í ó ú is 個 の Д`

deny: `/'.`

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [Unicode character classes](http://www.regular-expressions.info/unicode.html) to pick and choose.

Not sure, but I guess in your case that would be:

```
 preg_match('/^[\p{Latin}\p{Han}\p{Arabic}]+$/u'
```